# setup mtu automatically after system reboot

Tags: networking, boot, ubuntu-9.10

I have issues with slow internet and by changing mtu works fine for me.

I use Ubuntu 9.10 64bit system.

I have dynamic ip address setup

All the time after system bootup, I need to do the following command to make mtu setting take effect.

sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492

Are there any way I can set it up using startup program.

As you know, sudo prompt me root password.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245425/pptp-vpn-randomly-disconnects/1358055#1358055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to adjust your MTU permanently, do the following:

```
sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
```

If you are using a static address then find the interface you need and simply add the MTU line:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1 
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
mtu 1492
```

If you are using DHCP addresses then you need to set this before the interface comes up, by adding this line:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE mtu 1492
```

Then release and renew (or up and down) the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

(from [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3260380&postcount=11))

Comment: note this is pretty much the entire contents of the link Iain posted in his earlier answer.  @Kevin, please include a link back to your source when possible.  welcome to super user!

Answer (score -1):

See these [instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3260380&postcount=11) at the Ubuntu forums.